# how to hide the keyboard in android when click the edit text in alert dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, layout-inflater

i m using alertdialog to show my txt file content using edit text. here is the code used for alert dialog

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    file = new File(sdcard.getPath() + Constants.USERNOTE_FOLDER + "/"+value);  
                    System.out.println("txt file path name : "+file);

                //Read text from file
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                }

                System.out.println("text value : "+text);
                String filename=null;
                String toRemove = ".txt";
                if(value.endsWith(toRemove)) {
                     filename=value.substring(0,value.length()-toRemove.length());
                }
                System.out.println("file name : "+filename);

                 LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(ViewUserNote.this); 
                 final  View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.readusernote, null);
                 EditText readval = (EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.readtext);
                 readval.setText(text);
                 Builder alert = new Builder(ViewUserNote.this);
                 AlertDialog dialog =alert.create();
                 dialog.setTitle(filename);
                 dialog.setView(textEntryView);

                 dialog.show();
```

in this when i click the edit text the key board should not shown. how should i implements tis. pls any one help me....

Answer (score 2):

```
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

You can always disable your edittext, just setClickable,enabled,focusable attributes to false.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

```
alert.setNegativeButton(cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        saveimage();
                        InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: this code also not working for me. in my code i m using inflater to show the edit text. ill inflater is problem to hide the key pad for edit text

Comment: I guess problem was in getting the Dialog Interface event try my edited answer